# Unable to Refresh PowerBI Analyze in Excel

Tags: excel, powerbi, gateway, olap-cube, query-analyzer

I have installed the PowerBI "Analyze in Excel Updates" and "PowerBI Publisher for Excel". 
Every time I refresh the OLAP Cube it asks for login credentials. I am sure the login credentials are correct as I am using the same to log in to PowerBI Web. 
The error I receive in excel after submitting my log in details is: "The following system error occurred: (The operation completed successfully.)."

Kindly help as none of the users is able to use the "Analyze In Excel" function.

Answer (score 0):

The issue realted to the Windows 7 or Windows 2008 R2, plus the latest Analyze In Excle (SQL_AS_OLDB.msi build 14.0.700.314). You can try the build 13.1.4001.0 (SQL 2016 SP1). Download the ENU\x64\SQL_AS_OLEDB.msi from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54279.